# Clear the ith bit using bitwise operations swift

Tags: swift

I want to clear the ith element in an integer representation of a bit.

My attempt is the following

```
func clearBit (num: Int, i: Int) -> Int{
    let mask = (~(1 << i))
    return ( num & mask )
}
```

now my first example works as expected:

```
clearBit(num: 10011, i: 0) // == 10010
```

However, removing the 1st element

```
clearBit(num: 10011, i: 1) // == 10009
```

does not equal the expected result of 10010.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your second example should give `10001`, not `10009`...

Comment: Yes you're right, I copied my own incorrect value. It now has been corrected in the question.

Comment: `10011` is decimal number, binary literal is `0b10011`

Comment: You are mixing up decimal and binary numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the decimal number `10011`, not the binary number with the bits `1 0 0 1 1`. You should prefix the number literal with `0b` if you want it to be treated as binary:

```
let number = 0b10011        // 19
clearBit(num: number, i: 1) // 17
```

Later if you want to display these numbers as binary you can convert them to strings in base 2:

```
String(19, radix: 2) // "10011"
String(17, radix: 2) // "10001"
```

Comment: Great, seems to work. But in the docs: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AdvancedOperators.html can't find a reference. So is there a link, or why does it work this way?

Comment: ＠stevenpcurtis you need this docs: [https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/LexicalStructure.html#grammar_numeric-literal](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/LexicalStructure.html#grammar_numeric-literal)